# Angular project in .NET 6

Tags: angular, single-page-application, .net-6.0

We have been using the .NET 5 (and prior versions) angular SPA template and use Visual Studio to work on the api and Visual Studio Code for the ui (angular) and running a client side development server (4200) and it was simple to set that up.    It's brilliant to publish just one project to Azure through github and Azure Devops.

Has anyone solved this development experience/environment for .NET 6 as I've been unable to find it in documentation?

Thanks,
Lafi

Comment: Hi @Lafi - the Angular Spa template is exactly the same in .NET 6 (I created a new project earlier).  You should also be able to deploy it to Azure in exactly the same way as with .NET 5. Have you come across a specific problem?

Comment: I came here looking for the same answer. I haven't checked on my Windows machine yet, but in mac OS it turns out that .NET 6 Angular SPA template is using a fundamentally different SPA proxy pattern: https://guidnew.com/en/blog/an-alternative-approach-to-the-asp-net-core-spa-templates-using-yarp/

Comment: @Winthorpe I agree with drew the implmentaion has fundamentaly changed between .net 5 and .net 6.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly please check [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

I'm sure that this doc is enough to build and set up Angular and .NET 6.

and in visual studio 2022, you can use a template for Angular 12 and .NET 6.
[image]

I'm sure that we should set up comparing with that template.